# How To add Event And reminder to android calendar not using intent

Tags: android, calendar

I have tried Lot of code from stack over flow but i am able add event and reminder. i am new in android development. please help me.

Here is the code found to stack over flow

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
     ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
     Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cv.put("calendar_id", 1);
        cv.put("title", "Prog");
        cv.put("dtstart", cal.getTimeInMillis() );
        cv.put("hasAlarm", 1);
        cv.put("dtend", cal.getTimeInMillis()+1000*60*60);
        cv.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getID());

        Uri newEvent ;

        if (Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) >= 8 ){
            newEvent = cr.insert(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events"), cv);
        }   
        else{
            newEvent = cr.insert(Uri.parse("content://calendar/events"), cv);
        }   

        if (newEvent != null)
        {
            long id = Long.parseLong( newEvent.getLastPathSegment() );
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put( "event_id", id );
            values.put( "method", 1 );
            values.put( "minutes", 0 ); // 15 minut Before
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
            if (Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) >= 8 )
                cr.insert( Uri.parse( "content://com.android.calendar/reminders" ), values );
            else
                cr.insert( Uri.parse( "content://calendar/reminders" ), values );
        }
```